# How to check whether a specific page is time overdue by mouseover event?

Tags: jquery, session, authentication, timeout, authorization

From jQuery's document (or javascript) you see that jQuery's mousemove will be always invoked when you moving your mouse at some specific place.

My question is:

I'd like to make my asp.net to check whether it's session time out or not……So I suppose if someone's mouse doesn't move for a long time and when the next time the mouse begins to move, I'll check whether he/she is overdue or not. However, mousemove will invoke a lot of events one by one tightly……How to catch the last mousemove event?

Or **is there any other way to check session timeout by mouse moving** (Notice: I'm NOT using asp.net's form authentication because of my project's mechasim limitation).

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing it on mouse inactivity. Do it on click inactivity.
For every click restart a `setTimeout` for having the page timeout. This makes the code a lot easier and its simple to add global timeout variables. I.E

```
 var timeoutInterval = 100000;
 var timer1 = setTimeout(function() { doSomething(); doSomethingelse(); }, timeoutInterval );
 clearTimeout(timer1)
```

And if you must use mouse location.
Use `onmousemove` in JavaScript or `mousemove` in jQuery [here](http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/)

The logic becomes storing the last x,y position. If the difference from the last time is greater than the timeouttime then you can timeout.

Comment: Thanks but when someone uses his/her mouse move, I should also check whether the time is overdue or not.

Comment: Just as what I said above, if I handle the mousemove event, a lot of events get fired.

Comment: Right as I was saying. Why can't you store the last move event as a global?

Comment: Maybe I didn't make myself clear: What I want is when a user moves his/her mouse, check whether time is timeout or not.